# Member must have length- AWS Codepipeline error using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline

I have a `aws_codepipeline` resource in Terraform with two stages. The second one is a deploy using ECS:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
  name     = "my-codepipeline"
  role_arn = "my_arn"

  artifact_store {
    location = "codepipeline-eu-west-1-xxxx"
    type     = "S3"
  }

  stage {
    name = "Source"

    action {
      name             = "Source"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = "ThirdParty"
      provider         = "GitHub"
      version          = "1"
      output_artifacts = ["my_artifact"]

      configuration = {
        Owner  = "Myself"
        Repo   = "myRepo"
        Branch = "Master"
        OAuthToken = ""
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
      name = "Deploy"

      action {
        name            = "Deploy"
        category        = "Deploy"
        owner           = "AWS"
        provider        = "ECS"
        input_artifacts = ["my_artifact"]
        version         = "1"
        configuration = {
          ClusterName = "my-cluster"
          ServiceName = "my-service"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Error: Error creating CodePipeline: ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'pipeline.stages.1.member.actions.1.member.configuration' failed to satisfy constraint: Map value must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 1000, Member must have length greater than or equal to 1]
```

I think that this error is related to the configuration set up, but I don't find neither in Terraform docs, nor Google any issue related to this.

Comment: Can you edit your question for the example given to be a [mcve] please? That way people can run your Terraform code and iterate on it to be able to find a useful answer for you. As mentioned in that link, the example should be minimal (avoid things you don't need) and should reproduce the error you are getting when ran by itself.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Just added the terraform itself. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but I'm using pure cloudformation, I can't figure out the cause of this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error, and the issue was the syntax/format of my configuration data I defined for my provider.

In this case, my provider is CodeBuild, and it expects in its configuration to get some environment variables passed in using heredoc syntax. Originally, I had this:

```
      run_order = 1
      role_arn = ""
      category = "Build"
      owner = "AWS"
      provider = "CodeBuild"
      version = "1"
      configuration = {
        ProjectName = var.codebuild_build_release_project_image.name
        EnvironmentVariables = <<JSON
[
  {
    "name": "REPO_CONNECTION",
    "value": "repo_connection",
    "type": "SECRETS_MANAGER"
  },
 (etc etc)
```

What caused the error? I indented the Json configuration to the right about 10 spaces, so it would look nicer. Just the opening and closing brackets, and what was contained inside.

Doing that caused the error, and undoing it fixed the error. Redoing it caused the error again. Even though I have other sections that are indented and work fine. For now, I just have to chalk it up to a "sensitivity issue" with terraform and heredoc.

So, while I'm didn't have the exact same scenario as you, maybe that will shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I accidentally had my example secret vars file called:

"vars.secret.example.auto.tfvars" with the value:

github_token="" in it.

Since it still had "auto.tfvars" at the end it was reading it and messing things up and overriding my actual config value I believe. Changing the file name to remove "auto" did it.

Comment: yes, absolutely my case too! thanks for the heads up!